# Method error using jquery

Tags: jquery, methods, meteor

I keep getting that message in my console when calling my method:

> Exception while invoking method 'displayAndAddPost' ReferenceError: $
>   is not defined

However everything works fine so I am not sure how to properly use Jquery and stop that error message.

Here is the invoked method:

```
Meteor.methods({

    displayAndAddPost: function(word, counter) {

    var exist = Posts.findOne({word: word})

        if (word == "") {
            console.log("empty")

        }else if(exist != undefined ){
            //console.log(exist._id)
            Posts.update(exist._id, {$inc: {counter: 1}});
            $(".posts_form").hide();
            $(".posts_index").show();   

        }else{
            Posts.insert({
                word: word,
                counter: counter,
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
            $(".posts_form").hide();
            $(".posts_index").show();           
        }       
    }


});
```

Please note that although it says the $ is not defined the Jquery actions still works.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: please include the error printed to the server

Comment: The problem lies with the $ tag in my method as it says that is is not defined. I am using Jquerry so how should I code that method with the Jquery $ tag ? PS: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor methods code is executed both on the client and the server, however on the server jQuery is undefined because it's a browser only library.

You can enclose your jQuery browser specific code inside `this.isSimulation` sections to run them only on the client.

```
if(this.isSimulation){
  $(".posts_form").hide();
  $(".posts_index").show();
}
```

Alternatively, you should probably move the jQuery logic out of the method and execute it only on the client based on the result of the method execution.

Comment: Alternatively, `if ( Meteor.isClient ){}`